# Get current location with marker in android studio

Tags: java, android, maps

How to find current location with a marker. This code it finds the location but how to show the marker in current location?

```
 public void onSearch (View view)
    {
        ibtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageSearchButton);
        EditText location_tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
        String  location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if(location != null || !location.equals(""))
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try{
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Accidents Here"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

write onCreate() in your main activity class.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gooogle_map);

        TextView tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);
        Location l = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
            l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            if (l != null) {
                latitude = l.getLatitude();
                longitude = l.getLongitude();
                strAdd = getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude);
                tvAddress.setText("Complete Address : " + strAdd);
                break;
            }
        }

if (googleMap != null) {

MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps").snippet("Discription");

marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

// Moving Camera to a Location with animation
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

}
}
```

and this is your getCompleteAddressString().

```
private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<android.location.Address> addresses = geocoder
                    .getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                android.location.Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                Log.w("My Current loction address",
                        "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }
```

Comment: Not what l was looking for, you are giving the  lat1=23.043714;
                lang1=72.6077147;?